# listing data dependant on associated database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

Wasn't sure how to title this question but here it goes.

I have two tables, Hotdesks and Bookings. Users can book a hotdesk.

In my controller I have an array @eastdesks containing all desks with a location of "East".

What I would like to do is to **check which of these desks have been booked and display a list of available desks**. This is my controller:

```
@eastdesk = Hotdesk.order("code ASC").where(:location => "East")
@booking = Booking.all
```

And this is my code so far:

```
<% @eastdesk.each do |ed| %>
    <% @booking.each do |b| %>
        <% if b.date == Date.today && b.type == "Hot Desk"  %>
            <% if b.desk == ed.code %>
                <%= ed.code %> (Booked)
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This ONLY shows those that have been booked.

I appreciate it is very ugly because I have been playing around. It is quite confusing but the t tables are associated vie the 'desk' column in bookings and the 'code' column in eastdesk. (i.e. booking with desk 553 will link to the desk with code 553) Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help

**EDIT ----**

At the moment there are 2 desks in @eastdesk array (E90 and E23). The E90 desk has been booked for today and the E23 desk has not been booked at all. For the code above I am getting the following output:

```
E90 (Booked)
```

What I want to show is the desks that have NOT been booked. My Hotdesk model consists of:

```
has_many :bookings
```

I was thinking of adding the following to my bookings model but I am not sure as there ar different types of bookings and not all of them belong to a hot desk.

```
belongs_to :hotdesks
```

Comment: So you want to show those that haven't be booked? Or both?

Comment: Ideally I would like to show all desks and then have the ones that are booked be coloured red but that is a simple css thing once I figure this out

Comment: How do you determine if a `Hotdesk` is booked, programatically??

Comment: If the hotdesk code matches the desk code in the booking database for that specific date, then it is considered booked. Does that make sense?  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array holding 'Desk Codes' from booking table and use 'include?' method to check if this array contains the 'desk' value of @eastdeck.

**Possible Solution:**

```
@booking.map { |b| @booking_codes.push b.desk } // Creating a temporary array holding 'desk' from @booking
```

View:

```
<% @eastdesk.each do |ed| %>
  <% @booking.each do |b| %>
    <% if b.date == Date.today && b.type == "Hot Desk" && @booking_codes.include? b.desk %>
        <%= ed.code %> (Booked)
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

PS: This may not be the nicest solution, but it may help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Ill have a go play around with this! :)

Comment: I haven't actually had a chance to try it as I found a different solution. When I get a chance to try it out ill let you know! :)